# Magento custom module admin block display

Tags: magento, admin, block

struggling getting access to an admin block ive created.
Ive created a module...it has many elements, all working. Ive got header includes added to certain admin pages no problem, using my adminhtml layout update xml file.

The issue seems to be it cant access/see my block...so muct be referencing wrong, even though ive been following the 'module creator' extension files.

Another silly issue i think, been at this too long!  :)

First the code:

Mworkz/MyModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/MyBlock.php

```
class Mworkz_MyModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_MyModuleName extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
 public function __construct()
  {

    var_dump('WE ARE IN THE ADMIN BLOCK!');exit;

    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_mymodulename';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'mymodulename';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('mymodulename')->__('Item Manager');
   $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('mymodulename')->__('Add Item');
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

My layout xml (this file works, and is referenced right, as my admin header includes work)
Should point out i have a custom tab and controller...all working.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

  <mymodulename_adminhtml_mymodulename_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>Mworkz/MyModuleName.js</script></action> 
    </reference>
     <reference name="content">

        <block type="mymodulename/adminhtml_mymodulename" name="mymodulename" ></block>

    </reference>

  </mymodulename_adminhtml_mymodulename_index>
</layout>
```

I expect to see the var_dump stmt ive inserted....but it doesnt display.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

file naming! Simple caps issue...

My block file was called `'...Adminhtml/MyModuleName.php'`,

My block identifier inside the file was `'...Adminhtml_Mymodulename {'`

Another set of working code snippets for adminhtml block users i suppose!
Thanks